# Possible to add suffix to y-axis value (google chart)?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, linechart

I have a Google Line Chart showing temperature over time. I can't figure out how to add a suffix to the v-axis values. I would like for the values (for example `10` on the v-axis) to say `10˚C`.

I suppose it would be an option here:

```
var option = {
vAxis: {}
}
```

for adding a suffix to values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following format option...

```
vAxis: {
  format: '#,##0˚C'
}
```